# Difference between Graph API and GraphQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a difference between Microsoft Azure Graph API in Cosmos DB and its GraphQL provided by FaceBook?

Comment: This blog explains it well - https://zapier.com/engineering/graph-apis/

Answer (score 9):

They are two very different things even though they share the keywords "graph" in them.

1. CosmosDB Graph API is a query language to manage and query "CosmosDB graph database". Graph database unlike traditional databases, store information in the form of a graph (i.e., vertices and edges).
2. GraphQL on the other hand is a query language for a user API. Let's say that you have a build stack (the underlying platform could be anything) that has a REST endpoint. However the rest APIs typically are simple and do not let you specify complex filtering conditions. GraphQL is a way (or replacement to tradition REST API) by which the developer of the stack can allow clients to avail these complex functionalities.

Comment: Is there any GraphQL equivalent in Microsoft Azure?

Comment: Not that I know of.